# Missing dll files error in Objective-C programs

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

I am a beginner in Objective-C language. I have downloaded and installed `GNUstep msys` and `GNUstep core` and installed them in order, as mentioned in the downloads page of GNUstep.

But, I think that the installation isn't correct, because whenever I try to compile an Objective-C source file, it shows *fatal error Foundation/Foundation.h file not found*. Means, due to some reasons, the path to the header files isn't valid.

Although I am now successfully able to compile the source file with the `-I` and `-L` options, I faced another problem. After compilation, when I run the compiled *exe* file, it shows an error that many *dll* files are missing, such as `objc-4.dll`, `gnustep-base-1_24.dll` to name a few of them. But, I found all of these files present under the **/GNUstep/System/Tools** folder. When I copied these dll files to my main working (**home**) directory, it runs successfully without any errors.

Why is this happening? All the tutorials I found on the internet shows very simply the compiling and running of Objective-C programs in Windows without changing so many things. Am I missing something? I have searched many times in StackOverflow and also on the internet, but none of those solved this problem. Please help me and thanks in advance.

**P.S.** - I have installed GNUstep in the default **C:/GNUstep/** folder and included the **C:/GNUstep/bin/** and **C:/GNUstep/msys/1.0/bin/** folders in the *PATH* environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that there are more than one **gcc.exe** files present on my system for three different programming language compilers and their parent folders are included in the **PATH** environment variable. So, the `gcc` command conflicted with those three executables and therefore, the path to the `dll` files become invalid.

So, I had to move the GNUstep's bin directory to the top of the **PATH** environment variable to ensure that the GNUstep's gcc executable is used. And now, everything works like a charm.